# JavaFX import mp3 Files to ListView

Tags: java, listview, javafx, import

I spent many hours coding a method which imports .mp3 files to my ListView. Only the filename should be shown but it always says "no content in table"

```
fc = new FileChooser();
        FileChooser.ExtensionFilter filter;
        filter = new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("MP3-File", "*.mp3");

        fc.getExtensionFilters().add(filter);
        String path = fc.showOpenDialog(null).toString();
        media = new Media(new File(path).toURI().toString());
        mp = new MediaPlayer(media);

        String name = fc.getTitle();
        Playlist item = new Playlist(name);
        view.getTable().getItems().add(item);
```

Comment: Post a *minimal* example of code, an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a small example how it can be done: When the user clicks on the `Button` and selects a file in a `FileChooser` dialog successfully, the name of the file without the extension (.mp3) will appear in the `ListView<File>`.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;

import java.io.File;

public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        ListView<File> listView = new ListView<>();
        listView.setCellFactory(new Callback<>() {
            public ListCell<File> call(ListView<File> param) {
                return new ListCell<>() {
                    @Override
                    protected void updateItem(File file, boolean empty) {
                        super.updateItem(file, empty);

                        // Show file name without extension (when item not null and not empty):
                        setText(file == null || empty ? null : file.getName().substring(0, file.getName().lastIndexOf(".")));
                    }
                };
            }
        });

        Button button = new Button("Add mp3 file");
        button.setOnAction(actionEvent -> {
            FileChooser fc = new FileChooser();
            FileChooser.ExtensionFilter filter;
            filter = new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("MP3-File", "*.mp3");
            fc.getExtensionFilters().add(filter);
            File file = fc.showOpenDialog(stage);
            if (file != null)
                listView.getItems().add(file);
        });

        VBox vBox = new VBox();
        vBox.getChildren().addAll(listView, button);
        stage.setScene(new Scene(vBox));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```